# packets sometimes sent even if port not forwarded

Tags: router, port-forwarding

When behind a router, we need to forward port, on the router, for the specific host listening on that port.

If we don't forward the port, it will not always work on the host.

But why not always ?  Why can I still, sometimes, listen to that port on the host, even if the port is not forwarded on the router ?

Does the router guessing which host wants the packets ?

Comment: You can always listen but if you receive something on that server from the internet then teh router is doing port forwarding, and if your router claims it isn't forwarding then something strange is going on 'cos it is. The issue might be specific to some weirdness with your model of router in terms of what it's showing you and whether what it is showing you is up to date information as to whether it's forwarding or not

Comment: How do you test it?  Are you sure the traffic you're seeing is not local?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a port mapping created dynamically.

One of the most common is when the private LAN host sends an outgoing packet from that port. This works best if the NAPT gateway tries to preserve the outgoing source port number, and if it honors that port mapping even when unknown external IP address:port combos send packets to that port.

UPnP, NAT-PMP, PCP, and other protocols also provide ways for LAN devices behind a NAT to request port mappings be created so they can create listeners that can successfully receive incoming packets.

Comment: Thanks but this do not explain why it works less with no port forwarded. For example, using Soulseek : I get some search results if port is not forwarded. And I get a lot more search results if the port is forwarded.  What do make a search result successful with non-port-fwd, and another only successful when port-fwd is on ?